# ATI Mobility Radeon 4650: "GPU not found. Falling back to CPU device"

Tags: c++, gpu, ati, amd-processor, stream-processing

I have ATI Mobility Radeon 4650 on my computer. I have installed [AMD APP SDK v2.7 with OpenCL 1.2 SDK](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/Pages/default.aspx#one) and opened the sample applications. All of them indicates that GPU is not found. However, according to [Getting Started Guide](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/assets/AMD_APP_SDK_Getting_Started_Guide_v2.7.pdf) my video card is supported but beta only. I have looked to documentation and tried google but no help. How can I make the SDK to recognize my card? I am currently running on Windows x64.

Comment: You do have recent GPU drivers, yes?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, Just installed them

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/542583/opencl-on-ati-radeon-hd-4650